# How to handle session when a call is received

Tags: iphone, session, call

Please can you tell me how to handle session when a call is received.

Actually I'm playing with an online radio station and I want to resume that after call has ended.

Answer (score 3):

To add core telephony notification to your program, include the following code and compile linking to the Core Telephony framework. This code adds your program as a registered observer.

```
id ct = CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(ct, NULL, callback, NULL, NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);
```

To monitor the incoming notifications, you need to build the callback routine you supplied as an argument to the add observer call:

```
static void callback(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
 { ... }
```

For more plz read 
[Programmatically Handling iPhone interruptions](http://blogs.oreilly.com/digitalmedia/2008/02/when-it-comes-to-the.html)

Comment: +1 wow great information...But sorry i don't know how to Build callback routine